# Are Express app.locals shared across requests?

Tags: node.js, express

I have this doubt: let's say a user navigate to a path `/test?token=somelongstring`. This path, before rendering the view, sets two `app.locals`, for instance:

```
app.locals.email: "test-user-email" + user.email;
app.locals.name: "test-user-name" +  + user.name;
```

The `user` variable is taken from an API using the token query string variable.

Than another user goes to the same path, with a different token, setting those two variable with his values.

Now, let's say there is another route, `/display` that shows these variables. User 1 goes to that path after user 2 has set the `app.locals`. What user 1 will see? Will he see his values or the user2 values? I suppose user2, since `app.locals` are shared across the application, rather than the instance, but I'm not exactly sure (and unfortunately I can't test myself right now)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should consider reading the official documentation [here](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#app.locals)

Basically `app.locals` are properties that are accessed globally throughout the whole application. So basically each user will see the last assignment to these properties (email and name).

> let's say there is another route, /display that shows these variables. User 1 goes to that path after user 2 has set the app.locals. What user 1 will see?

He will see `user2` information because he/she assigned last his/her information to the properties.

Comment: Understand, so rather than `app.locals` I should use `req.locals`, since this is persisted through the request, right?

Comment: You're going to have to devise some kind of permanent data-store that knows how to differentiate between the various users so that each user's request gets data left behind by *their* previous request.  Neither `app.locals` nor `req.locals` are enough to do that.

Comment: I ended up using a session middleware and storing those values in the session object